# Flutter: How can I create a scoring system depending on the time I've spent in app for a game?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to make a game and I want to implement a scoring system depending on the time I've spent alive in game. I can't quite figure it out :(

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm fairly new to it, so I thought instead of integrating a scoring system depending on time, I would just use a stopwatch timer and the time elapsed is the score. But I'm so bad that I still haven't figured out how to start and stop the stopwatch...

Comment: Please include your code. SO isn't a free coding service, but we'll help you where you get stuck.

Comment: Oh sorry about that, I'm using a pre-existing app which is missing a scoring method and I'll be changing the sprites as well.

https://github.com/renancaraujo/trex-flame

Answer (score 0):

### Answer:

You have the **Timer** class in the async library of Dart. It receives a duration object, 
 starts the countdown asynchronously, and returns with a Future object (so that the rest of  your code can execute seamlessly). When the time is up, the Future becomes the object of the underlying type and this object is passed into the callback function.

https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-async/Timer-class.html

You can use this class to create a countdown every second, or five seconds, or some like that. Each time it expires, you can add one point in the callback function if the player is still alive, and restart the timer. This is just an example but hopefully you get the idea and your imagination already gets loose.

### Important notes for beginners:

In order to accomplish this, you need a solid understanding of asynchronous programming in Dart. Most importantly, the Future class and how futures behave.

If you are coming from the JavaScript world, you'll find that Futures in Dart are very similar to Promises in JS.

(There is plenty of well edited material on the official website https://dartlang.org/ which will help you to get familiar with Futures. If you are a beginner, you may need a day or two to grasp this concept but you'll find it was worth it.)

https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-async/Future-class.html